# JQuery .Click function unresponsive

Tags: jquery, function, click

New to using the click function. FIrst I incorporated it in a function triggered by an onClick event.

```
function clickroute(lati,long) {
      map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lati, long));
      map.setZoom(14);
$('#outdirections a').click(function() {
          $('#outdirections a').removeClass('directionsselect');$(this).addClass('directionsselect');
      });
  }
```

Fully functional but the first time the function is triggered the click function does nothing. I tried then leaving it separated and just having this in the script.

```
$('#outdirections a').click(function() {
              $('#outdirections a').removeClass('directionsselect');$(this).addClass('directionsselect');
          });
```

But that does nothing. How do we trigger the click function correctly.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you have is for binding, not triggering.

Handle your binding in `document.ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#outdirections a').click(function() {
      $('#outdirections a').removeClass('directionsselect');
      $(this).addClass('directionsselect');
      })
});
```

Then, any time an `<a>` within `#outdirections` is clicked, it'll remove/add the class.

[**Working demo on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/ybruG/).

Answer (score 0):

The event listener should be added after the load is completed:

in jQuery it's easiest to do like that:

```
$(function() {
  $('#outdirections a').click(function() {
              $('#outdirections a').removeClass('directionsselect');$(this).addClass('directionsselect');
          });
});
```

Where the `$(function() {` part is a short form for `$(document).ready(function() {`....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#outdirections a").live("click", function () {
              $('#outdirections a').removeClass('directionsselect');
      $(this).addClass('directionsselect');
      })

            });
```